# identify if a number is prime by % it by prime numbers smaller than its square root using python

Tags: python

I want to identify if a number is a prime number using these codes:

```
import math
import time

primes=[]

def is_prime_v2(n):

    if n==1:
        return False

    if n==2:
        return True

    if n>2 and n%2==0:
        return False

    m_d=math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
    d=3
    for d in (primes and d<m_d):
        if n%d==0:
            return False
    return True

for n in range(1,101):
    if is_prime_v2(n)==True:
        primes.append(n)
print(primes)
```

The terminal returns following error:

> "TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable".

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for d in (primes and d<m_d):
```

the Statement "d < m_d" equates to a boolean.
You should try to put it into the following if Statement, instead of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

When `primes` is empty `(primes and d<m_d)` evaluates to an empty list, due to the short-circuiting nature of the `and` operation. When it is not empty the expression evaluates to the result of `d<m_d`, which is a boolean. It seems you meant to filter `primes`, or in other words break the loop if that condition is not met:

```
for d in primes:
    if d >= m_d:
        break
    if n % d == 0:
        return False
```

This of course assumes that `primes` is in ascending order.